# Cannot run function

Tags: javascript, html

**Important note so people don't get caught out** (like I did): This may look like jQuery, *but it is not*.
<sup>Honestly, I should've known better. I use `$` for stuff other than jQuery. Oh well. Lesson learned! ~Niet the Dark Absol</sup>

Code :

(HTML):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="selector.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label id="id">A label</label>
        <script>
        $("label #id").clicked(function(){
            alert("ASDASD");
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

(JS):

```
/*
    NAME : SELECTOR.JS
*/

function $(attr){

    // Removed space in front of the variable
    while(attr.charAt(0) == " "){
        attr = attr.substr(1);
        if(attr == ""){
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // Completed the query
    if(attr.length > 1){
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(attr));
    }else{
        if(attr.length == 1){
            return new Object(document.querySelector(attr));
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}

Object.prototype.clicked = function(script){
    if(typeof(this) == "object"){
        if(this.constructor == Array){
            for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
                this[i].onclick = script;
            }
        }else{
            if(this.constructor == Object){
                console.log("SINGLE OBJECT : " + this);
                console.log("SINGLE OBJECT : ONCLICK : " + this);
                this.onclick = script;
            }else{
                console.log("ERROR : this.constructor is not 'Object' or 'Array'.");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }else{
        console.log("ERROR : typeof(this) is not 'Object'.");
        return null;
    }

    return this;
};
```

When I clicked the label, I cannot get the alert box seen.
What should I do? The file name is selector.js, for the js file.
I need the function to be ran. Pls help!

I think this is the minimized code.

Comment: Your selector is looking for "an element with ID `id` *that is a descendant of a `<label>` element*". Remove `label`, it's superfluous since IDs are unique. Additionally, `.clicked` should be `.click`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: gshhh.... downvoters are busy today :-)

Comment: Downvoters voted on my correct answer. Argh

Comment: @MarceloCamargo Actually, yours is the only answer that I downvoted... because it's wrong.

Comment: .clicked doesn't works on it. Or does it?
That is this that isn't calling the function of the event and not the ID of the element!

Comment: @MarceloCamargo You only addressed one of several issues. So did I (at first) but I only posted as a comment ;)

Comment: Pasting code and saying "help it doesn't work" doesn't qualify as a good question

Comment: I guess I did provided `selector.js` but I didn't told you I am __NOT__ using jQuery?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol "Additionally, .clicked should be .click" - not true. `clicked` is correct, OP extended the Object prototype, there is no jQuery involved. Apart from that, your comment answers the question.

Comment: @MrCode Well spotted. I guess I didn't expect something so... unorthodox.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol to be fair the question could be worded better to explain what he's doing.

Comment: @MrCode I've edited in a note to the question to help others not get caught out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is wrong, instead of `$("label #id")` it needs to be `$("label#id")`. With the space between `label` and `#id` you're searching for an element inside a `label` with `id="id"`, without the space you're searching for a `label` with `id="id"`.

Comment: Actually, it "needs" to be `$("#id")`. IDs are unique and qualifying them further is superfluous.

Answer (score -1):

The function

```
.clicked()
```

you used, is not a valid jQuery function. The one you are looking for is:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {  
       alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

See here:

http://api.jquery.com/click/